# how to handle dynamically created forms laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I want to know how to fetch name of checkboxes from dynamically created form. First I am displaying each records of data in a separate form then If records need to be deleted we will be able to delete. I am able to give different name as somename+id. But how do I know which name is going in the controller. As It is not clear that which name is going in the controller, I am not able to delete the record. I am doing it in laravel 5.4. Here is my code -

```
@if (isset($allcolors))
    @foreach ($allcolors as $color)
        <tr>
            <form method="post" action="/delete">
                {{csrf_field()}}
                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                <td>
                    <span class=""><input type="checkbox" name="deletecolor[{{$color->id}}]" value="{{$color->id}}"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div style="background:{{$color->web_color}}">a</div>
                </td>
                <td>{{$color->color_name}}</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
                        Delete
                    </button>
                </td>
            </form>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

then on form submission I want to fetch which I am doing like this -

```
public function destroy(Request $request)
{
    //
    $id = $request->input('deletecolor');
    $affected = DB::update("DELETE FROM vehicle_color where id = ?", [$id]);
    //echo $affected==1?"Successfully Deleted":"Delete Fail";


}
```

Comment: How are you getting the `name` input from the request when there doesn't seem to be one in your form, there's only `deletecolor[]`?

Comment: I am taking a variable like $i=1 and then I am incrementing and assigning name to the checkbox but problem is I am not sure at the time of submitting the form which id is going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have `$color->id`. Why not delete them based on that?

```
@if (isset($allcolors))
    @foreach ($allcolors as $color)
        <tr>
          <form method="post" action="/delete">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
            <td><span class=""><input type="checkbox" name="deletecolor[{{ $color->id }}]" value="{{$color->id}}"></span></td>
            <td><div style="background:{{$color->web_color}}">a</div></td>
            <td>{{$color->color_name}}</td>
            <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#colorDelPopup">Delete</button></td>
          </form>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

And in your controller:

```
public function destroy(Request $request)
{
    $ids = $request->input('deletecolor');
    // Instead of raw SQL, you can use the query builder to make your life a bit easier
    $affected = DB::table('vehicle_color')->whereIn('id', $ids)->delete();
    //echo $affected==1?"Successfully Deleted":"Delete Fail";
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. But $request->input('deletecolor') always coming empty in controller